# Prove that the series $\sum_{n =2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am trying to study the convergence of the series:

$$\sum_{n =2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$
First I have failed to use the D'Alembert test 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\ln (n+1))^{\ln (n+1)}}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}} =1.$$
So I can Conclude anything from here. 
I have also tried the integral Comparaison test but it was not soo clear.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Mathematica says it does converge to $5.71697(...)$

Comment: When you considered the integral test, did you sub $x=e^y$?.

Comment: @Sil Oh shoot, I didn't notice, and I *answered* that other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer:
$$
(\ln n)^{\ln n} = e^{\ln\ln n\cdot \ln n} = n^{\ln\ln n}
$$
and since $\ln\ln n>2$ for $n$ big enough,* you can conclude by comparison with $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$.

---

*${}^*$ Namely, $n > e^{e^2}$.*

Comment: Just like you previous answer ... ;-)) ... so (+1)